# Printing a dynamic text watermark on multi looped pages with CSS

Tags: php, css

On the University system am developing. I supposed to generate admission letters where each letter has two pages with a dynamic diagonal student name  .
The problem is on printing the watermark comes to only one page instead of staying on each page yet on @media screen am achieving it.

```
<style>
@media screen{
#adm #background{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:0;
        display:block;
        height:850px;
        width:78%;
    }
    #adm #watermark{
        color:#f0f0f0;
        font-size:80px;
        transform:rotate(310deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(310deg);
    }
    #adm #content{
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
}

@media print{
#adm #background{
    position:fixed !important;
        z-index:-1;
        text-align:center;
        display:block;
        height:850px;
        width:78%;
        background:gre
    }
    #adm #watermark{

        color:#f0f0f0;
        font-size:70px;
        transform:rotate(310deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(310deg);
    }
    #adm #content{
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
}
</style>
<div id='adm'>
     <div id='background'>
        <div id='watermark'>John Morgan</div>
     </div>
     <div id='content'>Admission content</div>
</div>
```

I want when loop and print the admission text watermark of the student appears diagonally in the each admission letter.

Comment: Which part are you going loop? Id attribute is unique.

Comment: Am going to loop admission letter with each having the a diagonal watermark of the student name.

Comment: The page-break-after property adds a page-break after a specified element.have a look on this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: this is what you want exactly https://codepen.io/elmsoftware/pres/wWGMaJ

Comment: I know that and it is breaking but the challenge is the watermark does not remain on the same page when i print. It goes only on one page

Comment: @NgodeDanuel first of all, you are wrong with using IDs for multi-time, and then can you give more details about your issue? as I find you want to print the `adm` divs in a single page when you printing, am I right?

Comment: The thing is The admission letter has two pages. Now the academic registrar can choose to generate and print one admission letter (Which has two pages) or can choose to generate and print  many letters(This can be all students admitted in a course). Now the problem is the watermark (Diagonal Student name) appear well in the all letters before printing ( Screen) but when i try to  printing it (The watermark of other below pages) jumps from other page to the first page. How can i set the printer such that the watermark remain like the way it appears on screen

Comment: @NgodeDanuel as I check your code you have the watermark text in the top of the page, you want to give the style to show it in the middle of the page, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the position of your element from the top in your print media section and as many you want you can increase that.
In your case, I set the `.background` CSS `top:50%;` and it shows the text in the middle of the page.

And If you set it to `top:150%;` it will be shown in the second-page middle.

```
@media print {
  .adm .background{
    position:fixed !important;
        z-index:-1;
        text-align:center;
        display:block;
        height:850px;
        width:78%;
        background:green;
    top:50%;
    }
```

I provide an online demo for your requirements, please check here.

https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/MdgGoL